# jquery $(document).ready and reading div content on load

Tags: jquery

Anyone know why this isnt working?

**css**

```
#test1
{
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#test2
{
    height: 50px;
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**html**

```
<div id="test1">
    test<br />
    Text
</div>
<br />
<div id="test2">
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($("#test1").val() != "")
    {
        $("#test2").val($("#test1").val());
        $("#test2").val("");
    }
});
```

I also have a link of the code here to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/FDe9N/4/

on the *$(document).ready* doesnt the site fully load before executing the code? and if so doesnt that mean the div should already contain the text? the code doesnt hit the code in the *if* statement as if the div was empty when in fact it does have text in it... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) only gets or sets the value of *form elements*. Since you're using `<div>` elements, you should use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) or [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#test1").html() != "") {
        $("#test2").html($("#test1").html());
        $("#test1").empty();
    }
});
```

Comment: I see you changed the line: $("#test2").val(""); 

I was wondering about this, in the original code he has if text1 isnt empty, set text2 to text1, then erase text2. This makes no sense as you just set it, so I am guessing this was the actual desired result.

Comment: @David, indeed, I guessed as much. Removing the contents of `#test2` afterwards could have left the questioner with the impression that the answer did not work.

Comment: @David Houde ya i meant to erase #test1 it was a typo.

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Use .html() not .val(). Val is for form elements.